# When did Captain Rumford die?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Act 4, you can come across the ghost of Captain Rumford in the Silver Spire. In all my playthroughs, I can't seem to find the part where he dies. How/when did he die?

Comment: Isn't the title of this question a bit of a spoiler?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you start the mission "Trailing the Coven" and leave New Tristram heading towards Old Tristram, you can find Rumford's corpse on a bridge not far from the town gates.

Clicking on him will make your character deliver a short eulogy (in my Witch Doctor's case, he said "Rest easy, friend...").  There's no in-game dialog that explains exactly how he died, but given the events of the mission prior, it's likely he was slain:

> while trying to protect the town from the cultists who kill Deckard Cain and take Tyrael's sword fragments.

[image]

Comment: Says the same thing on my barb (I think).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't show in the game until Act IV that he dies. I didn't know it until the ghost appeared. But it seems that Magdha and her followers killed him on their way to Tristram. Either that or some random Zombie got him while he was out strolling in the woods...

Answer (score -4):

he got killed by magda and the coven its not likely that he got killed by risen dead because thats what he has been fighting the whole time throughout act1 so and the coven is much more stronger

Comment: That's been said in a much more elaborate form more than one year ago, what does your answer add?

Comment: Reading can go a very long way.